# django passing post variables

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I'm doing a dynamic form with javascript in a django template. The number of inputs depends of the number of points that the user had made in the map. When I try to get the inputs in the view, I've got them disordered. When I see the Post variables with debug, the variables are arranged. Any idea?

template.html

```
 function getCoordinates(){                         
        var i = 0    
        form = document.getElementById('frm');          
        for (var i=0; i<points_l.length; i++){  

            inp=document.createElement('input');
            inp.type='hidden';
            inp.value=coord_l[i].lon+","+coord_l[i].lat;//setAttribute('value',coord_l[i]);
            inp.id='inp_'+i;
            inp.name = 'inp_'+i;
            form.appendChild(inp);                              
        }

        form.submit();          
    }
```

views.py

```
for k, v in request.POST.iteritems():

    if k.startswith('inp'):
        elems = v.split(',')
        lon = ''.join(elems[-1:])
        lat = ''.join(elems[:-1])
        coordinates_l.append(lat)
        coordinates_l.append(lon)
```

If I have 5 inputs, with the for loop I get the inputs in this order: inp_3, inp_4, inp_5, inp_1, inp_2. I need the inputs in order!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what the order is for but you can sort the `request.POST` dict (standard Python dicts don't have order) like this:

```
for k, v in sorted(request.POST.iteritems()):
    if k.startswith('inp'):
        elems = v.split(',')
        lon = ''.join(elems[-1:])
        lat = ''.join(elems[:-1])
        coordinates_l.append(lat)
        coordinates_l.append(lon)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yess!! Now it works perfectly. I need the inputs in order because they are coordinates, and I need to calculate the route between inp0-inp1, inp1-inp2, ...